# the fan wont stick properly

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

i bought a new motherboard which needs a fan that requires pins to be inserted in.
so i got a new fan so i started inserting it, i thought it was installed correctly but the cpu temp is getting high so much.
so i realized that not all the pins was inserted i tried to insert them but i cant.
if i want stick pins i either have to stick downer part without upper part or upper part without downer part.
specs are :
gigabyte ga-ep45-ud3l (motherboard)
pentioum 4 2mb 3.00ghz
nividia geforce 540 gtx
fan = core i2 duo (not the problem with the fan)
..................................................

[image: the motherboard im using]

Comment: Please tell us which fan you are asking about.

Comment: the fan is a core i2 duo fan

Comment: hello, are you still there?

Comment: You should add an annotated picture of the motherboard to your question.

Comment: okay, i got you a picture of my motherboard

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is with the fan. CPU fans need thermal paste where they press on the CPU, and a flying power lead to a socket on the motherboard. They will normally fit in only one direction.

Comment: sorry my english is not the best, i will explain for the way i can. okay so my fan got pins (4 pins) there is 2 downer part and 2 upper part,when i pressed the 2 downer part pins, i couldnt press upper part 2 pins

Comment: The motherboard manual should tell you how to fit it. Are you sure the fan is compatible with the motherboard?

Comment: yes, im 100% sure, the motherboard manual shows the same fan i got. but  i want know, what is the correct way to install cpu fan, i dont know if my way is correct or not

Comment: I don't have enough information on what you are trying to do or what you are supposed to do.

Comment: im sorry if my explaining not good. i thought of idea, let me try it and then i will back

Comment: It's not even clear whether you are talking about the mounting pins or the power connection pins.

Comment: You're talking about the pins that mount the fan to the mainboard, correct? You are NOT talking about the power cable and connector for the fan, correct? You're using a Pentium 4 CPU with a fan designed for a Core2. I'm going to say it's probably incompatible. Though, it typically requires a substantial amount of force to connect the mounting pins for Intel fans.

Comment: okay guys, i used my old fan that used to be pentium4 fan, and it worked just fine, i took a look at the manual and i got what i needed, sorry if i bothered you but thanks for help. i really appreciate your hard work guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the Fan connector, not the heatsink.

Your fan should have a 4 pin plug, which fits the 4 pin header on your mainboard, which is labled "CPU_FAN".

This should be your 4 pin CPU fan plug:

[image]

If your fan only got 3 pins it will still work.
There is a flap on one side of the CPU_FAN header on your mainboard which should align with your fan plug. If you plug a 3 pin plug on a 4 pin connector correctly your fan will still work.

If you got a 4 pin fan plug and a 3 pin fan header on your mainboard your fan will work aswell!

**Just make sure to align the flap on the header with your plug** like so:

[image: like so.]

Comment: i found the problem, thanks for helping anyway!                                                           and yea, that was my problem :)